# Routing with Lazy Loading modules not working with params

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular-routing

I understand there are a lot of discussions about lazy loading on site already. I am asking this question because I didn't find any applicable solution.

I am using routing with lazy loading in Angular 6.

This is what I am trying. In the parent module

```
{
    path: 'holiday',
    loadChildren: './holiday/holiday.module#HolidayModule'
  }
```

In child module.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '',component: HolidayBookingComponent},
  {path: ':id', component: HolidayBookingComponent}
];
```

while navigating `"localhost:4200/holiday"`, it redirects to `HolidayBookingComponent` correctly

but when I navigate to `"localhost:4200/holiday/3"` I get

```
GET http://localhost:4200/holiday/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Try aborting `ng serve` and restarting it again

Comment: what does this mean "shouldint :id have it's own component separate from ' ' "

Comment: tried ng serve again. no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', 
     children :[
      {path: '',component: HolidayBookingComponent, 
      {path: ':id', component: HolidayBookingComponent}
     ]
  },

];
```

Hope that will help!

working here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yuirrk

[image]

Comment: Tried it. No effect.

Comment: Thanks, but this also has not effect.

Comment: No problem, in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yuirrk  the route 'account' and the route 'account/:id' render same component. Is not that what you want ?

Comment: I dont see your code working in stackblitz, it is not showing anything on view.

Comment: I just found out, it works in edge, but not in chrome. :(

Comment: Can you check if you are able to run it on chrome?

Comment: Added a console.log , for you to see that is working  here https://angular-evvxrv.stackblitz.io , im on a mac and works in chrome, firefox and safari

Comment: I really appreciate your effort but it is still ot working in my app, I have asked another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53389882/angular-6-children-paths-of-lazy-laoded-module-are-not-working  Can you check this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183940/discussion-between-dheeraj-kumar-and-freepowder).