# Angular 6 - Children paths of lazy loaded module are not loading

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6, angular-routing

I am trying to work with routing in lazy loaded modules, but it is not working.

This is my app module routing.

```
  export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Home'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'holiday',
        loadChildren: './holiday/holiday.module#HolidayModule'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path:"**",
    component:P404Component
  }
];
```

This is RoutingModule for lazy-loaded module.

```
   const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', children: [
      { path: '', component: HolidayBookingComponent },
      { path: ':id', component: HolidayBookingComponent },
      { path: 'booking', component: HolidayBookingComponent },
      { path: 'review', component: HolidayReviewComponent }
    ]
  },

];
```

I can navigate to http://localhost:4200 and http://localhost:4200/holiday correctly.

**But when I try** http://localhost:4200/holiday/1 it throws 404 in console.

```
GET http://localhost:4200/holiday/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

These are dependencies in package.json in case you need it.

```
"@angular/cli": "^6.2.6",
"@angular/router": "^6.1.10",
"@angular/core": "^6.1.10",
```

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this example

```
   https://angular-svs3xe.stackblitz.io

   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svs3xe
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this for your lazy routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', component: HolidayBookingComponent },
      { path: ':id', component: HolidayBookingComponent },
      { path: 'booking', component: HolidayBookingComponent },
      { path: 'review', component: HolidayReviewComponent }
];
```